# How to check in only some parts of the program in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

Additional info: I thought it might be helpful to say that my forms and classes are in the same solution as the already updated forms.

In our company we have this project which 3 people are working on it. One works on the database part, me and another colleague of mine are working on making the UI ready and relating it to database which is MS SQL Server 2012 and we are programming in C# in VS 2012.

The problem is that I made this one form ready, but the server version is ahead of me. That is, if I check in the whole program, I will damage the project as some forms has changed and the version I have is older. I tried right clicking and checking in only the forms and classes which I, myself made and I have their latest version. They check in without any error or anything, but the problem is, when my colleagues or myself(after deleting my source project) try to get latest version, my forms or classes doesn't show up.

We also tried to check in the whole program but only accept those pending changes which are made by me, still no success.

The problem is, we are kinda afraid to play with the server version as a lot of effort has gone into it.

Any help will be really appreciated as I'm stuck with this problem and the manager won't give me more parts of the program to make until we can come up with some way to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned merging at all but I think this is the answer to your question.

When you work on an older version of the code (because your local code is older, or maybe the whole branch of the code is older), you need to merge the code into the newer version. When you merge, any potential conflicts are detected and you can resolve all of them manually. There's obviously tools to help you - one is built into Visual Studio but you can replace it with an external tool which may work better for you. Either way, you need to decide how to merge the code. You have a few options:

- take the whole code from the source (old code in this case),
- take the whole code from the target (new code in this case),
- merge the changes and take bits from each version based on your knowledge of the changes and how the code should look like.

---

As for why the forms don't show up, you probably didn't check in the changes to the project file so the new files are not part of the project as it exists in Team Services.

Comment: So, there isn't an automated solution to this matter? Cause, although I'm confident that I have enough knowledge about the codes we wrote, I'm not sure I know enough about the machine generated codes and settings. Will I need to manipulate these manually too?

Comment: Also, do you have any idea why the forms and classes that I checked in separately doesn't show up when we use the "Get Latest" function? :-?

Comment: You can resolve conflicts automatically and some of them can get resolved this way. But many cannot and they require your understanding of how the code was changed on both sides. As for the second question, you probably didn't check in the project file.

Comment: Got it, ye I didn't check in the project file. Only classes.
Thanks a lot

Comment: BTW, you seem to know a lot about this tool. Do you have any recommendation for us so we can get this problem out of the way? Any way of coding or something like that so we don't have to this every time or it is the only way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are certain things that help when merging: do not change the structure of files too much (e.g. move some files into a subfolder), do not move the code around in a file too much, make sure everyone uses the same style of whitespaces (the tools sometimes don't handle them well during merging).